# Add Json Operational layers info on Arcgis map

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I am trying to load operational layers data from the following JSON with no luck.

So far I tried the following

- add it as a graphic layer by using `graphicLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer(); graphicLayer.add(json); map.add(graphicLayer);`
- tried to normalize it and add as a graphic using `normalizeUtils.normalizeCentralMeridian`

Is there something I am missing, for reference I am trying to follow this example http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-web-map-json/index.html#/ArcGIS_feature_service_operational_layers/02qt00000017000000/

Its my first time with Arcgis, I have a sample JSON of a previously drawn line on the map that I am trying to load with no luck. Here is a JSFiddle of what I am trying.

https://jsfiddle.net/42wehk86/3/

> Really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create map from ArcGIS web map JSON, then you must use `createMap(itemIdOrItemInfo, mapDiv, options?)` from [`esri/arcgis/utils`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.arcgis.utils-amd.html)

[Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ags_createwebmapitem.html)